# How to preserve log scopes for unhandled exceptions?

Tags: c#

Say there's a function that uses a logger with scopes so that:

```
public void HttpFunction(ILogger log)
{
  using log.BeginScope("somescope");
  FunctionA(); // this can throw an exception
}
```

If `FunctionA` throws an exception, `somescope` won't be added to the exception that the logger automatically logs because the control will be outside the function block and the scope will be disposed off.

Is there a way to automatically have the logger log the exception, along with the added scope? I prefer not having a try catch block on `FunctionA` just for logging it out (and also the fact that if a developer later adds a `FunctionB`, they can make a mistake and forget to wrap it in a try-catch). Also, the catch block I would add would "handle" the error by doing a log-error-and-return-500, stuff that automatically happens anyways.

Also, I'm using Serilog, but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible to do what I want - without using a try-catch block at the outermost function, it's not possible to both preserve scopes and log automatically.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/Tolyandre/serilog-throw-context-enricher to get around this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a trick for this, it's [implemented in Serilog's own request logging middleware](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs#L70).

In your outermost exception handler, log the exception inside the `when` clause instead of in the `catch` block:

```cs
try
{
    function();
}
catch (Exception ex) when (LogException(ex))
{
}
```

Where `LogException()` can be something like:

```cs
static bool LogException(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex, "Unhandled excpetion");
    return false; // Don't actually catch the exception
}
```

Exception filters (`when` clauses) are special - they execute in the context in which the exception is thrown, rather than in the context that it's caught, so the `LogContext` is still available at that point.

Comment: I don't want to use an outermost exception handler - since the default behavior on error in an HttpFunction is to log the error and return a 500, I don't want to try - catch all functions that I call from inside the HttpFunctions to only log the error to preserve scopes and return a 500. 

So the question is, is it possible to preserve scopes without try-catch blocks?

Comment: No, it's not, as far as I know. You'll need to use middleware of some kind with the `try`/`catch` block if you need this.

Comment: Aah, also, it might not be clear from my answer - if you `return false` all you'll get is logging, the exception won't end up being caught (it will propagate back out to whatever is the next piece of exception handling middleware).

Comment: Okay. If there’s no way to do this without a try-catch, can you add that to your answer? I’ll mark it as accepted after that.

Comment: It is also important to note with this approach that the scope context will be available in the When clause only if code is synchronous. If your code is asynchronous, i.e. the exception is thrown into an awaited task and is processed in a catch block outside of that awaited task, the scope will not be available in the When clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Activity.Current?.AddTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.addtag?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-activity-addtag(system-string-system-string)) instead of `log.BeginScope` and [Serilog.Enrichers.ActivityTags](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ActivityTags/)

Something like

```
configureHostBuilder.UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    loggerConfiguration
        .Enrich.WithActivityTags()
        ...
});
```

and

```
public void HttpFunction(ILogger log)
{
    Activity.Current?.AddTag("somescope", "scopevalue");
    FunctionA(); // this can throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This assumes you use Serilog**

It's sort of roundabout way but it looks neat and it works:

Instead of scope store the scope variables inside the HttpContext Data via an injectable service like:

```
    public class RequestLogContext : IRequestLogContext
    {
        private const string HttpContextItemName = "LogContext";
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public RequestLogContext(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public void SetProperty(string name, object value)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> properties = GetLogContextDictionary();

            properties[name] = value;
        }

        public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> Properties => GetLogContextDictionary();

        private Dictionary<string, object> GetLogContextDictionary()
        {
            HttpContext context = _contextAccessor.HttpContext;

            if (context.Items[HttpContextItemName] is Dictionary<string, object> dictionary) 
                return dictionary;
            
            var newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            context.Items[HttpContextItemName] = newDictionary;

            return newDictionary;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
 _requestLogContext.SetProperty("UserId", model.Id);
```

Inject this data into the log via Serilog enricher like:

```
public class RequestLogEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private readonly IRequestLogContext _requestLogContext;

    public RequestLogEnricher() : this(new RequestLogContext(new HttpContextAccessor()))
    {
    }

    public RequestLogEnricher(IRequestLogContext requestLogContext)
    {
        _requestLogContext = requestLogContext;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (_requestLogContext is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var item in _requestLogContext.Properties)
        {
            var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(item.Key, item.Value, true);

            logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(property);
        }
    }
}
```

Register this enricher like

```
var configuration = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With<RequestLogEnricher>();
```

Now everything you add to this context during a request will be logged in case of an emergency.

Note. You might wish to make the SetProperty method return IDisposable and remove the property from the context on Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging you can achieve something similar using the following:

First, in Program.cs:

```
builder.Logging
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        // Log tags and baggage too
        options.ActivityTrackingOptions =
            ActivityTrackingOptions.SpanId |
            ActivityTrackingOptions.TraceId |
            ActivityTrackingOptions.ParentId |
            ActivityTrackingOptions.Tags |
            ActivityTrackingOptions.Baggage;
    })
```

Then, in appsettings.json (or Program.cs) set `IncludeScopes: true` on your logging provider.

Finally, in your controller/business logic/exception constructor:

```
Activity.Current?.AddTag("foo", "bar");
```

Any tags you add will then be included in all subsequent logs performed during the request/operation, including unhandled exception logs.